# Ruby on rails "No route matches"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to Rails and am just implementing some basic applications.  Just starting on my second app and have run into what is a basic problem, but Google is yielding me nothing.

Getting this error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"user", :action=>"admin_login"}
```

Here is my routes.rb

```
Blah::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :items, :cart, :user
end
```

Here is my `applications.html.erb` (the idea is this is a header of course, and I'm trying to create a link to 'login'.  Right now it's just supposed to set the 'login' session variable to '1'.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Blah</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
</head>
<body>

<div id="headerHolder">
    <div id="title">blah</div>
    <div id="menu">
        <div class ="menuItem">blog</div>
        <div class ="menuItem">
            <%= link_to "products",  :controller => "items", 
                                     :action => "index" %>
        </div>
        <div class ="menuItem">contact</div>    
        <div class="menuItem">
            <%= link_to "cart",  :controller => "cart", 
                                 :action => "index" %>
        </div>
        <div class="menuItem">
                <%= link_to_unless_current "admin", :controller => "user", 
                                                    :action => "admin_login" %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <%= yield %>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is my user_controller.rb

```
class UserController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def admin_login
    session[:login] = 1
    session[:cart] = nil
    flash[:notice] = "Admin user successfully logged in, cart reset."
    redirect_to :controller => :items
  end

end
```

What am i missing in my `routes.rb`? Or otherwise...am sure it's something daft.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add `admin_login` method to routes, like:-

```
map.connect '/user/admin_login', :controller => 'users', :action => 'admin_login'
```

Comment: so the automatic 'resources' route only handles 'index' and public facing methods to be accessed via html verbs?

Comment: Yes, the scaffold generated methods are added through resources.

Answer (score 21):

For Rails > 3 you should use the new routing syntax:

```
resources :items, :cart

resource :user do
  # Route GET /user/admin_login
  get 'admin_login', :on => :collection
end
```

See [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) for more information about routing.

Answer (score 1):

find  “config/routes.rb” file, edit, Locate the following line:

```
# See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes"
```

In this line add the following line, as follows:

```
map.connect '',:controller=>"index",:action=>"index"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
match 'admin_login' => 'user#admin_login', :as =>'admin_login'
```

default method for this call is post u can change method behavior by using

```
:via => [:post/:put/:get]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a new method in Rails 3. You can use the following:

```
get 'admin_login' => "user#admin_login"
```