# calling a ruby function from rails - it takes to a view which I don't want

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to make a ruby function called within rails. I followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375610/execute-ruby-function-in-rails), but I get redirected to

```
http://localhost:3000/my_func?arg=arg
```

which I don't want. I only want to execute the function when the button is clicked, but remain on the same page!

EDIT:

I modified the code, or better yet, made a scratch site just to solve this. I only did:

```
rails new eraseme
cd eraseme
rails g controller public home
```

app/controllers/public/home.html.erb

```
class PublicController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def my_func

  end
end
```

app/views/public/home.html.erb

```
<%= button_to "Button", {:action => "my_func", :arg => "arg"} %>
```

What I want to do, is execute `my_func` when I click the button. But when I click, I get

```
No route matches {:action=>"my_func", :arg=>"arg", :controller=>"public"}
```

Comment: Would this question help more? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605837/rails-3-call-functions-inside-controllers

Comment: @jab9bansai9 It did - modified the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, from what I can tell. I think you want to make a button that will send an AJAX/HTTP request to the Controller in order to call a function, that won't return a HTML file at completion.

In order to accomplish this, you must do the following.

1.) Set the HTTP routing for this call, this is within the config/routes.rb file.

```
match '/public/my_func' => 'public#my_func'
```

This allows your application to direct any HTTP requests with the following URL to call your method within the controller. Your button_to method will send this call with that URL due to the :action => "my_func" param.

2.) Also include the :remote => true, :form => { "data-type" => "json" } as more parameters to the button_to method.

This will transform the button from a traditonal HTTP request to an HTTP Request via AJAX request.

Let me know how this works, I think there are alternatives to using AJAX in this case, if its a very simple method then you can perhaps include it within the view as erb.

Comment: Here are some good links
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ajax_on_rails.html
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757380/ruby-on-rails-no-route-matches

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want. I started reading about AJAX, and later thought -mistakenly- that rails wouldn't need another parameter. It now complains about missing template. I'll go over it.